# how to get a hidden layer of tensorflow hub module

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I want to use tensorflow hub to generate features for my images, but it seems that the 2048 features of Inception Module are not enough for my problem because my class images are very similar. so I decided to use the features of a hidden layer of this module, for example:

> "module/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Mixed_7c/concat:0"

so how can I write a function that gives me this ?*8*8*2048 features from my input images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
module = hub.Module(...)  # As before.
outputs = module(dict(images=images),
                 signature="image_feature_vector",
                 as_dict=True)
print(outputs.items())
```

Besides the `default` output with the final feature vector output, you should see a bunch of intermediate feature maps, under keys starting with `InceptionV3/` (or whichever other architecture you select). These are 4D tensors with shape `[batch_size, feature_map_height, feature_map_width, num_features]`, so you might want to remove those middle dimensions by avg- or max-pooling over them before feeding this into classification.